# How do I launch a phone call or email in QML?

Tags: qt, nokia, qml

I want to be able to click on a phone number or email address text in an application I'm making in QML for Nokia phones and I can't find any documentation on how to do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qml-qt.html#openUrlExternally-method](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qml-qt.html#openUrlExternally-method%20Qt.openUrlExternally) and open a tel:12345 or mailto:my@address.com URL.